# Openfire database settings issue in mac

Tags: openfire, xmppframework

I have Openfire 3.7.1 installed on my Mac and have XAMPP installed aswell. I am having trouble configuring OpenFire. In the server settings I have given `san-imac.local.lan` as the domain name. The selected Standard database connection and picked MySql Database Driver. This is the databse URL `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test` and given the username password of XAMPP phpmyadmin. But it says

> A connection to the database could not be made. View the error message by opening the `"/logs/error.log"` log file, then go back to fix the problem.

First of all there is no such file in the `/logs` folder. What should I do to get this working and follow the procedures to get OpenFire up and running.

I need to build an app to connect to openfire for IM chatting like Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo using XMPP. If anybody could provide any guidance aswell, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that your database is setup correctly including the name of your database, database username, and user's password. If you have this correctly configured then your opens ire should work just fine. Note that it will not accept if the database username has an empty password or not enough access rights to the database.

I hope that those hints will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your password and username, I had the same error and it took me a while to figure out that I had my username wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.

log file is not getting created due to file write permission. To resolve this run OF server as follows

1. Run the openfire.sh file from terminal with sudo. This will start the OF with root access Now the error log file will be created.
2. My log file has error message as access denied to user @localhost. As I kept the user field blank in db connection page of openfire set up.
3. Keep the user field as root@localhost if u are using localhost.